# Android: Custom clock Ringtone

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-alarms

I want to set a custom audio file for the alarm clock app.

This is the code I came up with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 1)
 .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 16)
 .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_RINGTONE, "/system/media/audio/alarms/alarm1.mp3")
 .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
```

Now, it seems that whenever I choose to work with a file that is not located in `/system/media/audio/alarms/`

Android will not play it and fallback to a default audio file.

Why is that? Is there a permission required for using arbitrary audio as an alarm tone?

Comment: I guess accessing system audio or any system files is not possible unless your phone is rooted.